# What is the name and ‘grammatical’ function (not communicative function) of the word going in the sentences below?

Tags: grammar

What is the name and ‘grammatical’ function (not communicative function) of the word going in the sentences below?

1-  I like going to the cinema
2-  I am going to the cinema

Im very confused in this.

Comment: "Going" is a gerund-participle verb functioning as **head** of the gerund-participial clause "going to the cinema", which is functioning as catenative complement of "like" in 1. and of "am" in 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the -ing a participle in the sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361111/is-the-ing-a-participle-in-the-sentence)

Comment: @BillJ Might *going to the cinema* be better thought of as a VP in the second (because it cannot take a Subject)?

Comment: @Araucaria Like most non-finite clauses, it is subjectless, but it has an ordinary subject understood as "I" (see CGEL p1231 Class 2B). VPs function as heads of clauses, so at the first level down in the tree "going to the cinema" is a clause that happens to have no subject. It's no different to any other subjectless non-finite clause.

Comment: @BillJ Mmm. I'd always thought so too. But it's just occurred to me that any other non-finite clause can have a subject (apart from if, similarly, it's the complement of an auxiliary verb)

Comment: @Araucaria The presence of a VP spells the presence of a clause. I prefer H&P's catenative-auxiliary analysis to the dependent-auxiliary one, where "am going" is analysed as a VGp (i.e. "the verb").

Answer (score 1):

In both sentences, *going* is a verb, the main verb in a verb phrase [*going to the cinema*].

In the first sentence, that verb phrase forms a gerund phrase (or a reduced gerund clause -- "reduced" because there's no subject) which functions as a noun phrase, the object complement of the verb *like*. Since there's more than one clause, this is a complex sentence.

- [s *I* [vp *like* [np [s[vp *going* [pp *to the cinema* pp]vp]s] np] vp] s]

In the second sentence, that verb phrase is part of the verb phrase [*am* [*going to the cinema*]], which is an example of the progressive or continuous construction (not "tense"). It's not a noun or a clause, so there is only one clause and this is a simple sentence.

- [s *I* [vp *am* [vp *going* [pp *to the cinema* pp] vp] vp] s]

Answer (score 0):

The word going is the gerund form of the verb go to. This gerund form of the verb functions as a noun. In the first example, *going* is the direct object which you *like*. In the second example, you are assigning the object *going* (i.e. the state of going) to yourself.

In both cases *to the cinema* clarifies the sort of *going* that you either like or are assigning to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

*Going* in the first sentence is a gerund.  It acts as a noun.

*Going* in the second sentence is part of a verb phrase.  It is in the present continuous tense.

am/is/are +  (verb)-ing

Example:
What are you doing?
--I am watching TV.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *I like [going to the cinema]*.
>
> [2] *I am [going to the cinema].*

These are catenative constructions.

In both examples, "going" is a gerund-participle verb functioning as **head** of the bracketed gerund-participial clause "going to the cinema", which is functioning as catenative complement of "like" in [1] and of "am" in [2].

The term 'catenative' comes from the Latin word for "chain", which is appropriate here since each sentence contains a chain of two verbs, the second functioning as complement to the first.

Comment: In spite of the lack of attribution to the CGEL analysis, I don't understand the downvote here (especially when the other answers were upvoted).